# Disable the white end-of-document effect on scroll in Gedit 3.18.3

Tags: gedit

How can I remove or disable the white end-of-document effect when using the scroll wheel on Gedit 3.18.3?
See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Any thoughts on this one?

Comment: That's White thing is very annoying. Didn't get any solution so i switched to sublime and atom. They are better than gedit.